# pip and pip3 does not work on ubuntu 18.04 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, pip

I have this issue with pip & pip3, reinstalling them did not solve`enter code here`

```
  hp@hp-desktop:~$ python3.6 -V
Python 3.6.8
hp@hp-desktop:~$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
hp@hp-desktop:~$ python -V
Python 2.7.15+
hp@hp-desktop:~$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
hp@hp-desktop:~$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
hp@hp-desktop:~$ 

    hp@hp-desktop:~$ dpkg -L python-pip
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip2
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/baseparser.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/cmdoptions.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/check.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/completion.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/download.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/hash.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/help.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/search.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/show.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/wheel.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/compat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/compat/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/compat/dictconfig.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/locations.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/models
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/models/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/models/index.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/operations
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/operations/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/operations/check.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/operations/freeze.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/pep425tags.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_file.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/status_codes.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/appdirs.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/build.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/deprecation.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/encoding.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/filesystem.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/glibc.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/logging.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/packaging.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/setuptools_build.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/bazaar.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/git.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/entry_points.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/not-zip-safe
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-pip
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/Makefile.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/__init__.py
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/conf.py.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/configuration.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/cookbook.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/development.rst.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/index.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/installing.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/logic.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/make.bat.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/news.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/pipext.py
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/quickstart.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference/index.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference/pip.rst.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference/pip_download.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference/pip_freeze.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference/pip_hash.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference/pip_install.rst.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference/pip_list.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference/pip_search.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference/pip_show.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference/pip_uninstall.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/reference/pip_wheel.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/usage.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/user_guide.rst.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-pip/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pip2.1.gz
hp@hp-desktop:~$ dpkg -L python3-pip
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/pip3
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/baseparser.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/cmdoptions.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/check.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/completion.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/download.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/hash.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/help.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/search.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/show.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/wheel.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/compat
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/compat/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/compat/dictconfig.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/models
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/models/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/models/index.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/operations
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/operations/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/operations/check.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/operations/freeze.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/pep425tags.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_file.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/status_codes.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/appdirs.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/build.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/deprecation.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/encoding.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/filesystem.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/glibc.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/logging.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/packaging.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/setuptools_build.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/bazaar.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/git.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/entry_points.txt
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/not-zip-safe
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python3-pip
/usr/share/doc/python3-pip/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/pip3.1.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3-pip/changelog.Debian.gz
```

EDIT

Can you help also with this issue?

```
  Configurazione di update-notifier-common (3.192.1.7)...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
        import debian.deb822
    ImportError: No module named 'debian'
    Error in sys.excepthook:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
        from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from apport.report import Report
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
        import apport.fileutils
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
        from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
        import apt
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        import apt_pkg
    ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

    Original exception was:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
        import debian.deb822
    ImportError: No module named 'debian'
    dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto update-notifier-common (--configure):
     il sottoprocesso installato pacchetto update-notifier-common script post-installation ha restituito lo stato di errore 1
    dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di update-notifier:
     update-notifier dipende da update-notifier-common (= 3.192.1.7); tuttavia:
      Il pacchetto update-notifier-common non è ancora configurato.

    dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto update-notifier (--configure):
     problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
    dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di update-manager:
     update-manager dipende da update-notifier; tuttavia:
      Il pacchetto update-notifier non è ancora configurato.

    dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto update-manager (--configure):
     problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
    Configurazione di python-apt (1.6.4)...
    Segnalazione apport non scritta poiché il messaggio di errore indica la presenza di un fallimento precedente.
                                                                                                                 Segnalazione apport non scritta poiché il messaggio di errore indica la presenza di un fallimento precedente.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
     update-notifier-common
     update-notifier
     update-manager
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    `
```

Comment: @n_Iona Welcome to [su]! Your question is on-topic, but there's also a Ubuntu-specific forum, https://askubuntu.com. I recommend going there next time. Cross-posting is often frowned upon, but I have already pulled some extra eyes onto your post by asking the AskUbuntu community, [Is cross-posting is okay in this case?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18847/20358)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the `apt_pkg` module is missing. You can try reinstalling those with:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python3-apt python-apt --reinstall
```

If that doesn't help try purging python completely and reinstalling it with:

```
$ sudo apt purge "python*" "python3*"
$ sudo apt install python python3 python-pip python3-pip
```

Make sure to reinstall any additional modules that you could need.

Comment: Are you sure that I should erase all python related packages? `$ sudo apt purge "python*" "python3*"
$ sudo apt install python python3 python-pip python3-pip
`1,3GB of data?

Comment: You can try removing just python and python3, not all python packages. If not, create a backup list of all installed packages with `$ sudo apt list --installed "python*" | sed "s/\/.\+//"` and rerun apt install with all of those packages to reinstall them.

Comment: too late I messed up all installation idea on how to solve? hp@hp-desktop:~$ pip install 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
hp@hp-desktop:~$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

Comment: For anyone else reading: do NOT purge python or python3 on Ubuntu 18.04 it will remove critical system files. Depending on your system and what was removed you may recover by logging in to console and reinstalling